# On mandatory vaccines

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a list of *mandatory* vaccines for as many countries as possible.  The data set I am interested in could look like something along the following lines.

```
          | Chickenpox | Flu        | Shingles   |
----------|------------|------------|------------|
Borduria  | True       | False      | True       |
Ruritania | True       | True       | True       |
Syldavia  | True       | True       | True       |
----------|------------|------------|------------|
```

My motivation is to find vaccines that are mandatory in, say, [Borduria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borduria), but not in neighbouring [Syldavia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syldavia).

Answer (score 1):

The closest I have seen to what you're looking for are listings of countries where certain childhood vaccinations are mandatory:

- https://ourworldindata.org/childhood-vaccination-policies
- https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sansuthi/childhood-vaccination

You might be able to infer whether a vaccination is compulsory based on coverage rates found in WHO immunization data sets:

- https://immunizationdata.who.int/listing.html?topic=coverage&location=

I believe that there is significant regional variance within individual countries in terms of what is compulsory/mandatory, which would make a data set of this nature quite labour intensive to produce and maintain, which may explain why it is somewhat difficult to find this data online.